# Execute any command-line shell like into execve

Tags: c

In case this is helpful, here's my environment: debian 8, gcc (with std = gnu99).

I am facing the following situation:
In my C program, I get a string (char* via a socket).
This string represents a bash command to execute (like 'ls ls').
This command can be any bash, as it may be complex (pipelines, lists, compound commands, coprocesses, shell function definitions ...).
I can not use system or popen to execute this command, so I use currently execve.

My concern is that I have to "filter" certain command.
For example, for the rm command, I can apply it only on the "/home/test/" directory. All other destinations is prohibited.

So I have to prevent the command "rm -r /" but also "ls ls && rm -r /".
So I have to parse the command line that is given me, to find all the command and apply filters on them.

And that's when I'm begin to be really lost.

The command can be of any complexity, so if I want to make pipelines (execve execute a command at a time) or if I want to find all commands for applying my filters, I'll have to develop parser identical to that of sh.

I do not like creating the wheel again, especially if I make it square.
So I wonder if there is a feature in the C library (or that of gnu) for that.

I have heard of wordexp, but I do not see how manage pipelines, redirection or other (in fact, this does not seem made for this) and i do not see how can I retrieve all the command inside the commande.

I read the man of sh(1) to see if I can use it to "parse" but not execute a command, but so far, I find nothing.

Do I need to code a parser from the beginning?

Thank for your reading, and I apologies for my bad english : it's not my motherlanguage (thanks google translate ...).

Comment: why not make a user with limited permissions for your directory and use that user to execute the commands?

Comment: rm was just an example.
The idea is that I have to apply any filter on any command.
The filter's rules are not up to me, so if one day a filter say "ls can't be perfomed on path which containt the letter 'a'", well, I have to apply this rules.

Comment: @RemiThomas My advice is that you download the [Source code of Bash](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) and get the parts you need from it (the lexer, parser, forker, piper), then you build a rule stacker on top of it (something like ipchains). Creating all of this from scratch is gonna take you **a lot** of time and work. Of course, you can always create a simpler version of a lexer/parser by just splitting the input string by `;`, `|`, `&&`, etc and then running it through a rule stacker.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
I think it will take a lot of time to analyze and understand the source code but it will much shorter than coding from scratch.
But I'm surprised this isn't already available ... I'm not the first who want a complete sh parser. Am I ?

Comment: @RemiThomas Bash **is** the complete SH parser. If you want the **full** bash syntax, you have to take the code from it. Otherwise, you'll always end up with just a small subset of it. I think you should really rethink the design of your program... Why not make it a wrapper around bash, with it's own syntax? In other words, abstract BASH. Make you own syntax. Like `list foo` or `delete file.c`. Wrapping will give you great control over what is executed and what isn't. Is this a school project or a personal/job project?

Comment: @RemiThomas Plus, if you want the full connection plus some constraints, why not use SSH + user permissions?

Comment: @Enzo Ferber
I didn't understand that bash is the parser, well, shame on me ...
For your question : it's a job project.
My specification is the following : I receive on a socket a string that is a shell command and I have to execute it. But before execute it, i have to ensure that there is not a command in conflict with all the rules (like 'rm only inside this directory, etc etc). For executing the command, I can't use system or popen (I use execve). The rest is up to me. I don't understand the SSH thing ... Why SSH step in a shell parser ?

Comment: @RemiThomas I understand. The SSH thing was just something that came to my mind, but since you must write your own program, forget about SSH. Further, is it **necessary** to have full parsing capabilities? I mean, does it need to recognize **all of BASH** syntax? Or just recognize commands that can or cannot be executed?

Comment: You really plan to reimplement `bash`, attach it to a network, and allow commands to be run? Just use ssh, and set up passwordless login.  That's what it's **FOR**.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

> I am facing the following situation: In my C program, I get a string
>   (char* via a socket). This string represents a bash command to execute
>   (like 'ls ls'). This command can be any bash, as it may be complex
>   (pipelines, lists, compound commands, coprocesses, shell function
>   definitions ...).

How do you plan on authenticating who is at the other end of the socket connection?

You need to implement a command parser, with security considerations?  Apparently to run commands remotely, as implied by "I get a string (char* via a socket)"?

The real solution:

[How to set up SSH without passwords](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

> **Your aim**
>
> You want to use Linux and OpenSSH to automate your tasks. Therefore
>   you need an automatic login from host A / user a to Host B / user b.
>   You don't want to enter any passwords, because you want to call ssh
>   from a within a shell script.

Seriously.

That's how you solve this problem:

> I receive on a socket a string that is a shell command and I have to
>   execute it. But before execute it, i have to ensure that there is not
>   a command in conflict with all the rules (like 'rm only inside this
>   directory, etc etc). For executing the command, I can't use system or
>   popen (I use execve). The rest is up to me.

Given

> And that's when I'm begin to be really lost.

Because what you're being asked to do is implement security features and command parsing.  Go look at the amount of code in SSH and bash.

Your OS comes with security features.  SSH does authentication.

Don't try to reinvent those.  You won't do it well - no one can.  Look how long it's taken for `bash` and SSH to get where they are security-wise.  (Hint:  it's *decades* because there's literally decades of history and knowledge that were built into bash and SSH when they were first coded...)

Comment: The user at the end of the socket is already authenticate.

I think I have not give all the detail : Some of this command will be full bash syntaxe, and the rest of the command allowed will be "internal".

By "internal", I mean that I keep a full history of all command, and the "internal" command can modify this history (like "show", "clean", etc etc).
I understand that I can't reimplemt thing like that, but what can I do ? Is it really impossible to parse a command shell line ? Even with bash itself ?

Comment: @Tom's *The user at the end of the socket is already authenticate*?  How?  Password?  You wouldn't be passing that across the network in plaintext, would you?  Or are you just hoping that what's at the other end of your socket connection is allowed to be there? *Is it really impossible to parse a command shell line ? Even with bash itself ?* Given that bash doesn't do *I have to prevent the command "rm -r /" but also "ls ls && rm -r /"*, yes, it's impossible.  Any shell such as bash relies on the **OS** to prevent unauthorized users from doing "rm -r /".  How are you going to do that?

Comment: For example, even assuming you prevent `rm -r /`, how are you going to prevent this:  `ln -s /bin/rm /tmp/asdf; /tmp/asdf -r /`?  How are you going to prevent someone from executing a *script* that calls `rm -r /`?  And given your connection apparently has `root` access, how are you going to prevent them from dumping your hashed passwords from `/etc/shadow` for offline cracking?  Or installing a keylogger or other malware?  Do you know what commands you need to block to prevent that?

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that I have to say what appear to me as detail, really sorry.

The socket is connected on an openvpn connection.

The people who give me this assignements isn't here for the moment, but he requiere that he can execute any shell command.

As far as I know, I suppose there will be humans and programs which can send command on the socket. So the main purpose fo "filter" (or rules) on command is to prevent human error.

Comment: For your rm example, that's a good damn question ... 
I think the purpose of this program isn't to do security, because the security is managed elsewhere, but my program have to manage "command" (which can be a shell command or an "internal" command).

That's why I have to parse the command line. 
I'm really sorry to haven't give you all specification from the start.

Comment: @Tom's What do you mean by _internal commands_? Programs your own company wrote? You can always use SSH (as Andrew and I already suggested) and reconfigure `PATH` to search in a given folder first.

Comment: I try to explain this in the first comment, I misspoke ?
It's seems there is no way to have a complete bash parser in a C code, and I don't see again why SSH step in.

I spoke with my coworker who give me that assignement and we agreed that the bash verification will be made before, so there is no need for me to parse in the final.
Thanks to all, that was very rewarding.

Comment: @Tom's `I don't see again why SSH step in`  SSH "steps in" because you can't tell who is at the other end of a TCP connection.  **NO**, you **can't**.  Don't think you can.  You can try to reinvent SSH - but you won't do it anywhere near as well.

Comment: I don't have intention to re-implent SSH or bash, it would be really stupid if I do that. Again, I dont' want to parse the string for security purpose.
I just want to know if there a way to parse a string (bash syntax) in order to know which command will be executed (and with execve, I need to know). The fact is that I have to apply rules on this command is secondary.

Comment: @Tom's So you're **still** planning on running a TCP server, accepting TCP connections from any unknown, unauthenticated source, and then running whatever commands get sent over that connection?  And if you want to parse a `bash` command string, *run* `bash`.

Comment: The source isn't unknow or unauthenticated, because the tcp server listen on a OpenVpn connection. If I don't misunderstand, running bash will execute the command, isn't ? If so, that will be not matching what I need. For example, if i run bash with the command "mkdir /home/user0", does the folder will be created ? From my test, yes, and I don't want that.

Comment: @Tom's How do you listen on an existing connection?  You listen for *new* connections on an *open* port.  If your code calls `bind`, `listen`, and `accept` you do not know who is on the other end of that connection, even if it comes from `localhost`.  And if it comes from another host, the identity of whoever initiated the connection can never be verified outside of direct authentication because you simply can't trust anything at all as any remote host can always fake any response.

Comment: *For example, if i run bash with the command "mkdir /home/user0", does the folder will be created ? From my test, yes, and I don't want that*  If you don't want that then you have to recreate the *entire* set of permissions checks that the OS already provides.